# Firefox url location with &amp; problem

Tags: firefox, xslt, ampersand

I have next problem with Firefox. Using some xslt transformations leave no other choice, than to use "&" symbol in url.location for JS.
That works for IE, but doesn't for Chrome and Firefox.
I've made workaround by placing JS code in separate file. Is there any other solution of masking "&" symbol in xsl file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the HTMl code:  `&#38;`